# Hibernate 4 : SessionFactory v/s ServiceRegistry

Tags: java, hibernate, session

Here is some piece of code to create an object of Configuration Class & about the SessionFactory with ServiceRegistry.

```
Configuration cfg = new Configuration().addResource(
                    "employee.hbm.xml").configure();

            serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(
                    cfg.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();

            sessionFactory = cfg.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
```

What is `SessionFactory` ?

What is `ServiceRegistry` ?

What is the basic difference b/w `SessionFactory` & `ServiceRegistry` in Hibernate.

Answer (score 1):

In hibernate4 they have redesigned sessionFactory to pass the argument as Serviceregistry object.There are some issues in early approach you can understand from this  [check here](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-2578)